# Set of operations on Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have some sets here and I have to find the elements of each set but I don't know if this is right because there's no way to check correct answer in a set. I have already found complement of each set. Thanks to those who help me .

Universal/Union = { a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}

A = {a,b,c,d}                 A' = {e,f,g,h}

B = {e,f,g,h}                  B' = {a,b,c,d}

C = {a,d,h}                    C' = {b,c,e,f,g}

D = {c,d,f,g}                  D' = {a,b,e,h}

E = {a,b,c,f,g,h}            E' = {d,e}

Sets:

1.)[ [ [(A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')']' - [(B-D')'- (A-C')']' ]' - E ]'

2.) [ [ [ [ (A' - B')' -C' ]' - D' ]' - E' ]' ∩ [ ( A' ∪ B')' ∩ (E' ∩ D')' ]' ]'  ∩ ( B' '- C' ')' '

3.)[ B' ∩ [ (B' ∪ C')' - ( D' ∩ D) ] ' ]' ∩ [( E ∪ E')' ∩ (C' - E)']'

- The symbol  **'** is a complement symbol.
- I use the set of operations (Union, Intersection, Complement, and Difference)

Comment: Work step-by-step. you have $A$ and compute $A'$; you have $B$ and compute $B'$. Then compute $(A' \cap B')$ and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange Xela ☺! By the way, why do you want to calculate all these? Is this question from a book?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?`Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Hi! I have a preliminary exam next week and this looks like one of the examples my prof. Gave us but he didn't answer it, so I wanted to give it a try and I kinda confuse with the complement part. I don't know if he took it from the book.

Comment: @OveAhlman Like 90% of the sets, like in (A' ∩ B') = {  } then what should I do in the next set which is ( A' ∩ B')' since there's no element?

Comment: @XELA_1998 If $A' \cap B'$ is empty set, then its complement will be Universal set. I.e. $$\big( A' \cap B'\big)'=U$$ Because, the opposite (complement) of nothing (empty set) is everything (universal set).

Comment: @JaideepKhare Ok, I'm kinda getting it Thank you! :) So after the (A' ∩ B')' = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} I will proceed to ( C' ∩ D') = { b,e} And (C' ∩ D')' = { a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h} ...Am i right?

Comment: @JaideepKhare $\big(A' \cap B'\big)'$ is correct, but $(C' \cap D')' = \{ a,c,d,f,g,h\}$ , you forgot to remove b and e from U.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Why? I thought you should combine them all? and are Intersection means take all the same elements?

Comment: No!! **Complement** of A, that is A',  is defined as set of all elements in U but not in A. Since you got C'$\cap$D'={b,e}, when you take complement of this, you need to find the set of elements in U, but not in C'$\cap$D', that is U **except** {b,e}. Hence, (C'$\cap$D')'=U-{b,e}={a,c,d,f,g,h}.

Comment: @XELA_1998 and yes, intersection means all the **common** elements.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Ah! Ok! So, (A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')' = {a,c,d,f,g,h} And [(A' ∩ B')' ∩ (C' ∩ D')' ]' = {b,e}  ?? Is this right?

Comment: @XELA_1998 Absolutely correct!

Comment: @JaideepKhare Omg!!! I'm so happy right now haahaha.. To continue, B - D' = { f,g} (B - D')' = {a,b,c,d,e,h} , A - C' = { a,d} , (A - C')' = { b,c,e,f,g,h}    So, ( B - D')' - (A - C')' = {a,d}  ??? I'm confused XD

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes but that one is I already answer it..

Comment: Exactly; the second one has been answered. Thus, we can close the first one...